# Why does this error when I declared this properly?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

Here’s my “problematic” code which I slaved all night trying to make it work. I tried all types of variations of ArrayAdapters. I even tried ones online.

```
package com.balut.testinggrounds

import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Toast
import com.balut.testinggrounds.R

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Spinner

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    // access the items of the list
    val languages = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Languages)

    // access the spinner
    val spin: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)
        if ( spin != null) {
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages)
            spin.adapter = adapter

            spin.onItemSelectedListener = object :
                    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>,
                                            view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                            getString(R.string.selected_item) + " " +
                                    "" + languages[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                    // write code to perform some action
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Note: I typed that again and again just to make sure I didn’t make a mistake.

Comment: post your logcat!

Answer (score 4):

Move the code to a lifecycle function such as `onCreate()` rather than being on the class body level.

Comment: Okay, I tried it and it doesn’t error now but the app crashes when I run it in the emulator

Comment: @Gowapo With a crash the first step is to have a look at the stacktrace in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

`resources` is shorthand for `getResources()` and it requires a `Context`, which the `Activity` doesn't have when it's first constructed (which is when your member variables are initialised). You'll have a context by the time `onCreate` runs.

`findViewById` requires the activity to have inflated its layout, which doesn't happen until `setContentView` is called in `onCreate`. If it's run at construction time (like here) then it will fail to find `R.id.spinner`, and `spin` will be null - but you've declared it as the non-null type `Spinner` so that will cause a crash.

Either do like @laalto says and initialise these in something like `onCreate` (preferably using `lateinit` so they don't need to be nullable), where you have your context and layout view, or wrap them in a [lazy delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy) and access them in or after `onCreate`.

And post your error stacktraces! That way people can tell you exactly why you're getting a crash